# For Loop Execution Time

Tags: php

My database contain 200 data and I am trying to execute for loop to check the downline of users and as per their downline assigning level to them but it is taking too much execution time and as a result server is not responding in time. What should I do?

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM members LIMIT 1");
$row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
$id=$row3['id']; 

for ($i=$id;  ; $i++) {  
    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE d!=0 AND id=".$i);
    $row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
    $level1=$row3['level'];
    $d=$row3['d'];
    $downline1=$row3['downline'];
    if ($d!=$downline1) {
        switch ($level1) {
        case 1:
            $downline1=($d-3);
            mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE members SET downline='$downline1' WHERE id=".$i);
            break;
        case 2:
            $downline1=($d-12);
            mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE members SET downline='$downline1' WHERE id=".$i);
            break;
        case 3:
            $downline1=($d-39);
            mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE members SET downline='$downline1' WHERE id=".$i);
            break;
        case 4:
            $downline1=($d-120);
            mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE members SET downline='$downline1' WHERE id=".$i);
            break;
        case 5:
            $downline1=($d-363);
            mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE members SET downline='$downline1' WHERE id=".$i);
            break;

        }

        $query1=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM downline");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
            $level=$row['level'];
            $downline=$row['total_downline'];
            if ($downline1==$downline){
                mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE members SET level='$level' WHERE id=".$i);
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider to visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to check out how to ask good questions on SO and get help answers from the community.

Comment: `LIMIT 1` without `ORDER BY` means you're just picking an unpredictable row out of the `members` table. What are you trying to do with that query?

Comment: Why don't you change the second query to `SELECT level FROM downline WHERE total_downline = $downline1`, instead of looping through all the rows testing `total_downline`? Or join the two queries: `UPDATE members JOIN downline ON members.downline = downline.total_downline SET members.level = downline.level WHERE members.id = $i`.

Answer (score 1):

Your for-loop is an **infinite loop** since you do not define an ending condition: `for ($i=$id;  ; $i++) {`

Better would be to fetch all members and iterate over them with a while loop:

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM members");
while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){
    $id = $row3['id'];
    // do what you used to do in for-loop here
}
```

This way you loop over all members in your DB, even if there are gaps in their ids like Barmar mentioned.

On a sidenote, move your update query from within switch-cases to after the switch. It is always the same for each case.

**Edit**: fixed fetching members from DB

Comment: looping through the count of members won't necessarily find all member IDs. What if there are 10 members and the IDs go from 101 to 110?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to update all members, you don't need to do a `SELECT` and a loop, just put all the logic in the SQL:

```
UPDATE members
SET downline = d - CASE level
                    WHEN 1 THEN 3
                    WHEN 2 THEN 12
                    WHEN 3 THEN 39
                    WHEN 4 THEN 120
                    WHEN 5 THEN 363
                END
WHERE d BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND d != downline
```

And the second update can then be:

```
UPDATE members AS m
JOIN downline AS d ON m.downline = d.total_downline
SET m.level = d.level
WHERE m.d BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

You can actually do both updates at once:

```
UPDATE members AS m
LEFT JOIN downline AS d 
ON m.d = d.total_downline +
    CASE level
        WHEN 1 THEN 3
        WHEN 2 THEN 12
        WHEN 3 THEN 39
        WHEN 4 THEN 120
        WHEN 5 THEN 363
    END
SET m.level = IFNULL(d.level, m.level), 
    m.downline = m.d - CASE level
                        WHEN 1 THEN 3
                        WHEN 2 THEN 12
                        WHEN 3 THEN 39
                        WHEN 4 THEN 120
                        WHEN 5 THEN 363
                    END
WHERE m.d BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND m.d != m.downline
```